# Protect value with fingerprint

Tags: android, security, fingerprint, biometrics

I’m implementing a “use fingerprint instead of password” feature for devices with nexus imprint.

It’s fairly easy to prompt for a fingerprint and see if was correct or not but I’m scratching my head trying to protect a value with fingerprint, I’m following this example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog but there is no “recover value with fingerprint”, it only explains how to store it

any good example of something like that?

The API expects a password so the general idea is:

- user activates "protect with fingerprint"
- is asked for the password
- if correct, is asked for fingerprint
- if correct, password is securely stored
- for any subsequent logins, when touching the fingerprint scanner, if correct, the value is decrypted and sent to server for login

Answer (score 2):

Okay, found the way, just for the record, here are the steps:

Init Cypher for decryption:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

Create the CryptoObject with Cypher:

```
CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManagerCompat.CryptoObject(cipher);
fingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject, 0, cancellationSignal, callback, null);
```

Check the `onAuthenticationSucceeded(AuthenticationResult)` and get the value:

```
Cipher cipher = authenticationResult.getCryptoObject().getCipher();
byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal("1234".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This was useful. Thanks.